# как преобразовать список в множество и наоборот

Tags: python-3.x

как преобразовать список в множество и наоборот

Comment: `set(my_list)`, `list(my_set)`

Comment: @MaxU, оформите как ответ)

Answer (score 6):

Просто вызвав соответствующий конструктор:

```
In [93]: my_list = [1,2,3,2,2,3,4]

In [94]: my_set = set(my_list)

In [95]: print(my_set)
{1, 2, 3, 4}

In [96]: my_list2 = list(my_set)

In [97]: print(my_list2)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```